# What are Pharaoh, Grandmother, and Monarchy deletion patterns?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I was looking at the docs for [Django CTE Trees](https://django-cte-trees.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and saw the text:

> Multiple delete semantics: supports Pharaoh, Grandmother, and Monarchy deletion patterns.

This meant nothing to me, so I did a bit of googling - and found nothing!

Does anyone know what "Pharaoh, Grandmother, and Monarchy deletion patterns" are?

Comment: Wow, I'm legit surprised I can't seem to _actually find_  anything related to what the docs are talking about...

Comment: Reading the source might help: https://github.com/petrounias/django-cte-trees/blob/90036a35eb025514539b7c7e996ac9e8e92cd9b8/cte_tree/models.py#L113

Comment: It helps a bit... I haven't got time at the moment to work out what each mode is doing, but it seems that these terms have been made up by the developers of django-cte-trees, seeing as there seems to be literally nothing elsewhere on the web. I have created an issue on their github asking for clarification: [Docs: explanation of "Pharaoh, Grandmother, and Monarchy deletion patterns" · Issue #12 · petrounias/django-cte-trees](https://github.com/petrounias/django-cte-trees/issues/12)

Answer (score 1):

Original author here: I encountered these terms in a book on Common Table Expressions over a decade ago, but I cannot remember nor find the book today - I will update if I do.

Pharaoh mode means all descendants are also deleted.

Grandmother mode means the parent of the deleted node becomes the new parent of all children of the deleted node (this requires multiple roots if a root node is the subject of deletion). The order of the children is preserved.

Monarchy mode means the first child of the deleted node becomes the new parent of the remaining (if any) children of the deleted node (its former siblings). What constitutes the first child depends on the ordering of the CTE as with all other operations.

Comment: I'm guessing Pharaoh mode is so named because of the Pharaohs of Egypt being buried with their servants who were sacrificed...